# How to get sum of doubles in list using stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Program is about purchases of companies. And i need to get some specific data from them using lambdas and streams.

**COMPANY**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
    private String name; // nazwa firmy
    private String cityHeadquarters; // siedziba firmy
    private int employees; // ilość pracowników
    private List<Purchase> purchaseList; // lista zakupów wykonanych przez firmę (co firma kupiła)


}
```

**PRODUCT**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    private String name; // nazwa produktu
    private double price; // cena produktu

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Product)) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return Double.compare(product.price, price) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(name, product.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, price);
    }
}
```

**PURCHASE**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Purchase {             // klasa reprezentuje zakup
    private Product product;        // produkt zakupiony
    private LocalDate purchaseDate; // data dokonania zakupu
    private double quantity;        // zakupiona ilość produktu
    private UNIT unit;              // jednostka zakupu (np. w gramach)

}
```

**MAIN**
unfortunately [Main](https://github.com/chodek/javagda34/blob/master/src/main/java/zadaniaDomowe/Main.java) class is too big, but it consist mainly of created objects: products, companies and purchases. With list off all companies at the bottom.

How to return company that spent the most money on purchases? I tried with something like this:

```
 // 11. Zwróć firmę która dokonała zakupów na największą kwotę
    private static Company zad11(List<Company> companies) {
        List<Company> list1 = companies.stream()
        .map(c -> c+ c.getPurchaseList().stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getQuantity()*p.getProduct().getPrice()))
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and im getting error:

Error:(552, 60) java: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  java.util.List<LambdyIStrumienie.Purchase>
  second type: java.util.List<LambdyIStrumienie.Purchase>

Comment: I can't even post list of companies its too long. Look at this here it is: 
https://github.com/chodek/javagda34/tree/master/src/main/java/zadaniaDomowe

Comment: Hey, Check I created the Gist here: https://gist.github.com/vishwaratna/47952c81976ade500231757662d8c5cc

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mapToDouble` then terminate with `sum()` method. Something like this:

```
double sum = vals.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grouping feature of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
Map<Company, Double> map = companies.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(                                 // To Map<Company, Double>
        Function.identity(),                               // Key: Company
        Collectors.summingDouble(c -> c.getPurchaseList()  // Value: Sum of all purchases
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(p -> p.getProduct().getPrice())   // ... of all products and its prices
            .sum()                                         // ... as sum
        )   
    )
);
```

The key is each `Company`, the value of the map is the sum of prices of all its products within purchases - this assures [`Collectors::groupingBy(Function, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

The downstream collector [`Collectors::summingDouble(ToDoubleFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) is responsible for summing all the prices.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need the company who spent the maximum amount, then you need to have max()**

```
    Stream<Double> doubleStream = companies.stream().map(s -> s.getPurchaseList()).flatMap(k -> k.stream().map(j -> j.getProduct().getPrice()));
    List<Double> collect = doubleStream.mapToDouble(k -> k).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Optional<Double> max = collect.stream().max(Double::compareTo);
    System.out.println(max.get());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
90000.0
```

GIST I created: https://gist.github.com/vishwaratna/47952c81976ade500231757662d8c5cc

Comment: If you need the company who spent the maximum amount, then you need to have `max()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Add new property in Company class as below

private double pruchseTotal;

companies.stream().forEach(c->c.setPruchseTotal( c.getPurchaseList().stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(p->p.getProduct().getPrice()*p.getQuantity())) ));
Company company = companies.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Company::getPruchseTotal))).get();
```

Comment: it meses the data in main. All of the products now lacks new field "total"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for getting the `list` of `Double` values.

```
 List<Double> doubleList= values.stream().map(vals-> 
          vals.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleVal).sum()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```